# Disable/enable a page on a popup being shown/hidden in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, popup

I am using  a windows phone user control to show a popup. I used this because My app may be calling for a log in @ several points(not if already logged in). I was able to display the popup(used a class). This is my first time exposure to mobile apps.  What I need is to disable the page from which the popup is called and enable it once we are logged in or cancelled the popup. Please find my code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;


namespace Project1.Utilies
{
    class TALogin
    {


        public void display_cspopup()
        {
            Popup popup = new Popup();
            popup.Height = 300;
            popup.Width = 400;
            popup.VerticalOffset = 200;
            Pages.PopupController control = new Pages.PopupController();
            popup.Child = control;
            popup.IsOpen = true;

            control.popuplgnbtn.Click += (s, args) =>
            {
                popup.IsOpen = false;

            };

            control.popupcnclbtn.Click += (s, args) =>
            {
                popup.IsOpen = false;

            };
        }
    }
}
```

AS you may have guessed, PopupController is the controller  created for Popup UI(xaml file).

Thanks,
Akhil

Comment: As far as i know, you'll not be able to hide or disable a xaml page.

Comment: @Kulasangar: Thanks. But I was able to disable the page(this.IsEnabled = false;). I am unable to enable it back

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is have two secondary Grids in your Primary Grid and set the visibility to visible or collapsed as per you require!!

your xaml should look somewhat like this:

```
<Grid x:name="ParentGrid">
<Grid x:name="ChildGrid1">
<!-- your work -->
</Grid>

<Grid x:name="ChildGrid2">
<!-- your work -->
</Grid>
</Grid>
```

assume you have a button in your grid, on its click event you can collapse any of the grids in this manner!!

```
//in click event of the button:

ChildGrid1.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Hope this helps!! :)

Comment: Thanks @Taeb: But this was not what I meant. I was able to disable the page (this.IsEnabled = false;). But I cannot enable it once the popup is gone. I will be calling the popup in multiple pages. so a generic approach of enabling and disabling the page from which the popup is invoked is what i need